# Trigger to delete all but x rows per index

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables: `posts` and `server_options`.

`posts` consists of:

- `no`
- `date_created`
- `server_id`
- `user_id`
- etc

`server_options` consists of:

- `no`
- `posts_per_user`
- `server_id`
- etc...

A user is only allowed `server_options.posts_per_user` posts per server. To limit this, I have a trigger executed before insert and update to `posts`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `bi_posts` BEFORE INSERT ON `posts` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    SELECT posts_per_user INTO @posts_per_user FROM `server_options` WHERE server_id = NEW.server_id LIMIT 1;

    SELECT COUNT(0) INTO @post_count FROM `posts` WHERE server_id = NEW.server_id AND user_id = NEW.user_id;

    IF @post_count >= @posts_per_user
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: post limit exceeded.';
    END IF;
END
```

Simple enough. However, what I'd *like* to do is also add a trigger to `server_options` on update. If `posts_per_user` changes, it should remove any "excess" posts for that server from posts.

For example. If some users have 5 posts in a server, and the `posts_per_user` is reduced to 3, it should delete the oldest and keep only 3 for that user for that server.

Any pointers on where to begin? `no` is AI PK, so we can sort by that rather than `date_added` to make things easier.

I was thinking this (it works), but to me it seems like a bad approach:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `au_server_options` AFTER UPDATE ON `server_options` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.posts_per_user < OLD.posts_per_user
    THEN
        DELETE FROM `posts`
        WHERE NEW.posts_per_user <= (
            SELECT count(0)
            FROM (SELECT no, server_id, user_id FROM posts) AS posts_temp
            WHERE
                `posts`.`server_id` = `posts_temp`.`server_id` AND
                `posts`.`user_id`   = `posts_temp`.`user_id`   AND
                `posts`.`no`        > `posts_temp`.`no`
            ORDER BY `posts`.`no`
        );
    END IF;
END
```

I'm not looking at huge amounts of entries. Maybe a 100,000 or so.

Thanks, y'all!

Comment: It's very often quicker to create a new table keeping just the rows you wish to retain, and then deleting/archiving the old table, and renaming the new table.

Comment: See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/mysql-keep-the-10-most-recent-rows-for-each-user

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm not too concerned with speed. Obviously it should be considered, but unfortunately that approach - while probably the easiest - isn't an option for me.


@ArianKhosravi - I'm no MySQL expert by any means. Are you reocmmending the procedure approach by Abdul Manaf or the answer by Lukiahas?


Do you see anything terribly wrong with what I've come up with in the original post? I don't expect `posts_per_user` to be updated often at all, and I expect an average of 100K entries or so.